# Implementing TestFX in the Eclipse

Tags: testing, javafx, junit, testfx

I would like to write tests to my project in JavaFX and I've read that I have to use TestFX, so I want to implement the library to my eclipse. But I still can't resolve my problem (look at picture). I was looking for a solution but it was unsuccessful. I've imported all the necessary jar files to use TestFX...
Have you any idea where can be a reason?

When I move my mouse on the "red light bulb" there is information "The type com.google.common.base.Predicate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

[Eclipse Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c43Kh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the Jar of the [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have to* use TestFX, it's just a good third party library. There are many other options like JUnit.

Comment: I'm writing tests for first time to my project and I just found a TestFX tutorial. That's why I would like to use it because I didn't find JUnit tutorial with JavaFX and I don't know how it works with controllers.